# Why doesn't typescript-eslint specify a peerDependency on TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

typescript-estree uses the [TypeScript parser](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/c480eab/packages/typescript-estree/src/parser.ts#L2) but doesn't specify it as a dependency or peerDependency in [package.json](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/5792aa1/packages/typescript-estree/package.json#L43).

Why? It seems this must be intentional, but then it users of the library who don't have TypeScript in node_modules will get a runtime failure?

Asking because I want to understand the trade-offs involved in using peer dependencies vs. implicit dependencies.

Comment: Do you mean `typescript-estree`, or `typescript-eslint`, or both ? (The title states eslint, but the text only mentions estree)